# How to reverse a string array in place using a swap function and pointers? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

my assignment is to reverse a string array in place. I must use a swap function that swaps individual characters and this swap should be in a loop. Pass two character pointers to the swap function to manipulate the locations in memory. So here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(char *a, char *b){ //swap function that accepts two char     pointers
    char temp = *a;          
    *a = *b;                 
    *b = temp;
}


int main()
{
    char array[5] = {'H','e','l','l','o'}; //string hello
    char *start = array[0]; //pointer for start of string
    char *end = array[array.length-1]; //pointer for end of string
    for (int i = 0, int j = array.length - 1; i < j; i++, j-- ){
        swap(start,end);
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ //print reversed array to user
        cout << array[i];
    }

}
```

I have little experience with pointers so I may be using them incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Other than the obvious syntax error (`array.length` won't work), have you tested this code?  At quick glance, your algorithm looks fine.

Comment: `char *start = array[0];` you can't initialize a pointer with a char, you should do `char *start = array;`

Comment: `for (int i = 0, int j = array.length - 1; i < j; i++, j-- )` can be simplified quite a bit. Compare `start` and `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At lines

```
char *start = array[0];
char *end = array[array.length-1];
```

`array[0]` is a character, not a pointer. You can reference it to get a pointer with `&array[0]`, or take advantage of the fact that the name of an array can be used as a pointer to the first element like `char *start = array`.

When you did

```
for (int i = 0, int j = array.length - 1; i < j; i++, j-- ){
```

The problem is that there is no such thing as `array.length` in basic C arrays. You should either keep track of the length of an array separately or use `std::size(array)`. **Note that this gives you the size of an array (compile time constant), not the length of a C-style string.** Although a solution better than both of these methods is to just use an `std::string`, which keeps track of its length beside being much easier to use than C-style strings.

Also, you can't declare two variables in the same statement separated by a comma unless they are the same type, in which case you omit the type of the second variable like this: `int i = 0, j = length`.

Another thing, you should learn about using references to pass the arguments to your swap function so that you don't have to reference them all the time when using the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made the changes you suggested and I no longer got errors for the pointer lines; however, I am still getting errors on this line: 
    for (int i = 0, int j = 4; i < j; i++, j-- )

Comment: You can't initialize two variables in the initialization statement of a for loop (the very first component before the `;`). Just init the variables outside this statement or just init one in there and the other on the line before your `for` loop

Comment: @EatatJoes You can do `for(int i = 0, j = length - 1; ...)` as far as I know.

Comment: My bad, you are right. just not initialize with another type; `int i = 0, float j = 5`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks guys it finally compiles!

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track but you kind of lost it with your pointers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(char *a, char *b) {
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned int array_size = 5u;
    char array[] = { 'H','e','l','l','o' };

    for (int i = 0, j = array_size - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) { 
        cout << array[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```